# Quantum (spin/thermal) Hall v.s. (Spin/Thermal) Quantum Hall effects

Tags: condensed-matter, experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, definition, quantum-hall-effect

Are the following concepts defined correctly, as I understand:

1. **Quantum Hall effect** is a quantum-mechanical version of the Hall effect, observed in two-dimensional electron systems subjected to low temperatures and strong magnetic fields, in which the Hall conductance $\sigma_{xy}=J_x/E_y$ undergoes quantum Hall transitions to take on the quantized values $\sigma_{xy}=\text{quantized} \cdot e^2/\hbar$.
2. **Spin quantum Hall effect** is characterized by the spin current induced in the transverse direction respect to a spatially varying Zeeman
   field ($B$). See [for example Ref Phys. Rev. B 60, 4245 1999](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.60.4245)
3. **Quantum spin Hall effect** describes the transverse spin current induced by an electrical voltage. It is also [an example of 2-spatial dimensional topological insulator or symmetry protected topological order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_spin_Hall_effect).  (Protected by charge conservation symmetry and spin-$S_{z}$ conservation symmetry but NO time reversal symmetry)
4. **Topological insulator**: Some people distinguish topological insulator (charge conservation symmetry and time reversal symmetry) from  [Quantum spin Hall effect (charge conservation symmetry and spin-$S_{z}$ conservation symmetry but NO time reversal symmetry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_spin_Hall_effect). But some people mix Topological insulator with Quantum spin Hall effect.

And what are the differences between

5. [**Quantum thermal Hall effect**](https://www.google.com/search?q=quantum+thermal+hall+effect)

v.s.

6. [**Thermal quantum Hall effect**](https://www.google.com/search?q=thermal+quantum+hall+effect)?

How are they defined and contrast to each other?

Are there also standard conventions of

7. **quantized (spin/thermal) Hall**

and

8. **(Spin/Thermal) quantized Hall effects**

as well occasionally seen in the literature? What conceptual and physical phenomenon do they characterize?